# MySQL injection commands

Tags: mysql

What are ALL THE MySQL commands that can be used to do an injection in a code?

I have disabled UNION and CONCAT.

I have a very basic application so no need for any complex queries so what else can I disable to make sure injections are a non issue?

Yes I have sanitized all variables as far as I know. The issues is it is a project with multiple parties and I have noticed some sloppy work in some libraries I have been handed to work with.

I was thinking on getting all the post variables sanitizing them an putting them back but that would be quite a complex task due to the complex multidimensional nature of some post variables.

Comment: `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE`, for a first three to start with.

Comment: What language is this app in?

Comment: If you only use prepared statements, injection shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Why instead of looking for commandos to disable you don't just sanitize the input? Probably you can find a working class, function, or library to do it easily on whatever language you are using.

Comment: If I wore to take all the request array and loop through it all and sanitize. Would that be a good option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injection is possible with just about any type of SQL statement.
The only safe method of avoiding injections is to use prepared statements and bind data to query parameters.

Comment: Like he said use MySQLi or PDO. Assuming your programming in PHP.

Comment: Yep - sql injections need to be handled in your application code, not at the database level. That said, you could disable everything but SELECT to at least ensure your data isn't modified, but that would likely make for a useless application.

Comment: You cannot always use prepared statements and I can't write the whole code myself. I must use the modules I am given. I am developing the main site but certain components are foreign coded or open source libraries. The libraries are solid but everything does not seem to be to solid.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply disable keywords, look at this example:

SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='*' AND password = '**`whatever' OR password <> '`**'

You need to escape the user input, before adding it to the SQL statement (e.g. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`). Even better would be to use prepared statements with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

> […] to make sure injections are a non issue?

That cannot be done. If SQL injections are *possible*, then they are an issue.